# check format of date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, date-format, momentjs

I am taking input from calendar in my screen which is of this type

```
DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a
```

but user can provide date from keyboard. Now I have to check whether user has provided the date in correct format or not. I am heavily using moment.js in my application and validating it like this

```
 if(angular.equals(moment(scope.modelValue).format('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a'), 'Invalid date'))
{
       alert('date is not correct');

}
else
{
alert('date is correct');
}
```

It is working fine but the problem is if I provide input like '18-Feb-2015 2'
then it is converted to '18-Feb-2015 00:00 am'. so now how to check that format is exactly what I want ? please help ..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For checking date format you could use:

```
moment(checked_date, DATE_FORMAT).format(DATE_FORMAT) === checked_date
```

Comment: 1. Looks like this is a string comparison. In which case leading zeroes in Date and Month wouldn't work. **e.g. 03-Jan-18 vs. 3-Jan-18**. Also it is better to use _moment(checked_date, DATE_FORMAT).isValid()_ to check against a particular format.

Comment: @Sriram for validating format ensure moment is in strict mode as highlighted by @josh-rickert in the answer below! `moment(checked_date, DATE_FORMAT, true).isValid()` which is available in moment > 2.3

Comment: `moment(checked_date, DATE_FORMAT, true).isValid()` always returns `true`, so that's no good. It seems to work properly on with strict checking, as given in wallop's answer below.

Comment: doesn't works when time becomes hour and minute is 00:00 i.e                                           1. 2020-04-25 00:00:01  2. 2020-04-25 00:00:21 will always give false so it doesn't work for one minute can't rely on that

Answer (score 51):

if it's just for checking the below is a better alternative

```
moment(scope.modelValue, 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a', true).isValid()
```

Comment: Moment should be in strict mode if you want it to match that exact format. That is done by passing in `true` as the third arg.

Comment: @JoshRickert that is only for version 2.3 and above.

Comment: doesn't works when in time  hour and minute is 00:00 i.e                                                   1. 2020-04-25 00:00:01  2. 2020-04-25 00:00:21                                                                   will always give false so it doesn't work for one minute can't rely on that

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a particular date format then you can also use Array of formats,

```
moment(checked_date, [DATE_FORMAT1, DATE_FORMAT2]).format(DATE_FORMAT)
 === checked_date
```