# How to find format (not validate against a particular format) of date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-format

I have a given Date string, which is already formatted by moment.js by someone.
I want to get that format.

I have checked existing questions and came across this one -
[check format of date with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587018/check-format-of-date-with-moment-js)

The solution provided is not returning the format of the date. Rather it is validating against some given formats.

I want a function getMomentDateFormat like this -

```
var dateString = field.value; //"Nov 30, 2017"
var dateFormat = getMomentDateFormat(dateString ); //I want dateFormat = "MMM DD, YYYY"
```

Comment: Which is the value of `field.value`? What is your expected result? What did you try so far?

Comment: VincenzoC, The value of `field.value` is given in comment - "Nov 30, 2017"
The expected result is also given in comment - "MMM DD, YYYY"
I have gone through documentation and search a lot over internet. I have tried with few methods, which does not fulfil the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Parse Date Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/parseformat/) plug-in:

> This plugin extracts the format of a date/time string.

Here an example (anyway it returns `MMM D, YYYY` instead of `MMM DD, YYYY`):

```js
function getMomentDateFormat(input){
  return moment.parseFormat(input);
}

var field = { value: "Nov 30, 2017" };
var dateString = field.value; //"Nov 30, 2017"
var dateFormat = getMomentDateFormat(dateString);

console.log(dateFormat);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gr2m.github.io/moment-parseformat/moment-parseformat.js"></script>
```

PS. Do not use scripts directly from https://gr2m.github.io/, refer [github repo](https://github.com/gr2m/moment-parseformat).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want. but unfortunately, I cannot use any other library. Is there any way in moment.js or pickaday.js?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do the same thing using only moment core, anyway you can look at the library code (that is quite small) and take the code you need for your usecase.