# Can you get the date format pattern from a date string with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to be able to get the date format string from a date string in JavaScript.

I also am using Moment.js as well if this can be achieved using this.

As an example if I have a string such as

> 2019-01-01 15:00:00

I'd like something like this returned

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

I've searched the documentation but cannot find any answers to this.

Comment: I think you can use [Parse Date Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/parseformat/) plug-in, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47567930/4131048) an example.

Comment: This looks exactly what I am after thank you! If you want to add an answer I will accept

Comment: you can `format` function of `moment` object http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question, I want to get the format rather than set the format, the answer from Vincenzo seems to be what I am looking for

Comment: oh you want reverse of it.

Comment: Correct, thank you for your comment though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Parse Date Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/parseformat/) plug-in:

> This plugin extracts the format of a date/time string.

Here a live example:

```js
const input = "2019-01-01 15:00:00"
const dateFormat = moment.parseFormat(input);

console.log(dateFormat);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gr2m.github.io/moment-parseformat/moment-parseformat.js"></script>
```

Edit after @VLAZ comment, `parseFormat` has the [`preferredOrder`](https://github.com/gr2m/moment-parseformat#preferredorder) option:

> `parseFormat` tries to figure out the the order of day/month/year by itself if it finds 3 numbers separated by `.`, `-` or `/`. But if it can't, it will fallback to `preferredOrder`, which can either be set as an object to differentiate by separator, or as a simple string.

Comment: This tends to assume US format if the data is in format `06/05/2019` It does correctly identify `16/05/2019`, though. Just a word of caution.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is ok I can live with that limitation as it will mostly be used within the US anyway

Comment: @VLAZ you are right, the plug-in has the `preferredOrder` option to address this issue, I've edited my answer after your comment.